# jQuery function in jQuery dialog window

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I have an aspnet webform with four jQuery cascading dropdown lists. This form works well when I open it independently. However, my requirement is to open this form as a jQuery dialog in response to the click event of a button control. The form loads, but the cascading dropdown lists dont work. When I select a value in the first dropdownlist, I get an error message that the jQuery function for onChange event is not defined:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'GetSenders' is undefined

I use the following code to open the jQuery dialog and load the webform into the window:

```
$('').dialog({
    dialogClass: 'DynamicDialogStyle',
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).load(url);
    },
    close: function (e) {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
    },
    height: 500,
    width: 540,
    title: 'Dynamic Dialog'
});
```

I am using jquery-1.11.1.min.js and jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js.

Comment: you need to initialize plugin within complete callback of `load()` which is when the new html exists. See jQuery api docs for `load()`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I do not know how to initialize the plugin. I went through the documentation for load(), but could not figure out how to initialize the plugin. Can you please explain a bit more?